# Linux Multimedia Studio

Tags: language-support, lmms

During Ubuntu installation, made the computer location France. However, I need English as the LMMS language. There is no language choice within the program. There is no solution at the developer website. How can I download an English version?

Comment: What language do you have now? There's always a default language.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the English locale file for LMMS in place of the expected French locale file. Open the terminal and run:

```
cd /usr/share/lmms/locale
sudo cp fr.qm fr.qm.bak
sudo rm fr.qm
sudo mv -T en.qm fr.qm
```

LMMS will now load en.qm as fr.qm and you will now have English text in your LMMS installation.

<sup>Reference: http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/precise/all/lmms-common/filelist</sup>